# Ejecutar una tarea programa en segundo plano dentro un rango de hora en .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-core, timer, asp.net-core-mvc, task

Tengo el siguiente codigo, el cual necesito que se ejecute dentro de un intervalo de horas, en este caso desde las 21:00 hasta las 23:59 todos los días, para que envie correos:

```
public class TimedHostedService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private int horas = 0;
    private readonly ILogger<TimedHostedService> _logger;
    private Timer _timer;
    
    public TimedHostedService(ILogger<TimedHostedService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Timed Hosted Service running.");            
            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
            TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {

        TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(21, 0, 0); //12 am
        TimeSpan end = new TimeSpan(23, 59, 0); //4 am
        TimeSpan now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

        if ((now > start) && (now < end))//valida dentro del rango de horas
        {
          EnviarCorreo();
        }
     }

  public void EnviarCorreo(){
    ......// Code
    ......
 }
}
```

Pero el codigo se ejecuta una sola vez que está publicado en el servidor, es decir, que al revisar al día siguiente si llegó el correo el cual es el metodo EnviarCorreo, no tengo ningun email, es como si solamente se ejecutara una vez que está publicado.

El codigo está hecho en .Net Core, y para que se inicie despues de publicarlo en el servidor, debo llamar al cualquier metodo del controller (lo cual es lo unico que se me ocurre por ahora, pero quizas podría ser mejor y no sea necesario).

Pero lo que realmente necesito de su ayuda, es que el proceso se pueda ejecutar todos los días dentro de un horario definido, ya que como les dije antes, al día siguiente ya no llegan los correos.

Alguna idea, desde ya, gracias por su atención.

Comment: Tu idea.. no es la correcta.. tu programa solo debe enviar el correo al iniciar y luego terminar.. no debe el contar el tiempo, debe ser una tarea programada en tu sistema operativo.. y ahi, se acaban todos tus problemas...

Comment: @gbianchi, es que yo quiero enviar correo dentro del rango de hora establecido

Comment: @Danilo ¿Has utilizado el `Task Scheduler` del Windows?

Comment: @fredyfx, pero para ejecutar archivos .bat, pero como sería en este caso si quiero hacer referencia a un proyecto web api publicado?

Comment: Es que basicamente esto no deberia ser un proyecto web, deberia ser un ejecutable comun y corriente... estas pensando mal la arquitectura de tu sistema...

Comment: ¿Podrías justificar los motivos por el que es necesario un proyecto web api?

Comment: @fredyfx, la idea es que puede estar en ejecución siempre, a pesar de no haber iniciado sesión. Y si lo transformo en una aplicación windform, no se si resultará o será suficiente. O como podría hacerlo.y dejar en segundo plano

Comment: te explico, si te creas un proyecto de consola, se genera un .exe, a este archivo lo vas a llamar desde el Windows Task Scheduler, dependiendo de la configuración, podrías ejecutar dicho .exe cada minuto, cada hora, en una hora determinada. Por eso, hacer Windows Forms no tiene sentido, tampoco hacer un web api, ¿o sí?